# Cannot access Angular app served on CentOS virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, apache-http-server, centos, webserver, angular-cli

I have been a front-end developer for a few years and am trying to teach myself the back-end of things so I am very new to all of this. I have CentOS minimum running on a VirtualBox with Apache httpd installed. Network is set to bridged adapter (I have also tried setting it to NAT and setup port forwarding with the guest and host port set to 4200). I went through [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7) tutorial and managed to set up the basic html page described (though I was never able to get a custom domain name to work) and access it from my host machine at http:// server-ip. I've since installed angular cli and am just trying to serve the new myApp on the VM and access it from my host (windows 10) machine and only see "the site cannot be reached ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT". I have tried ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 as I've read in other questions and I still get the same. I'm currently looking into port forwarding but I'm not sure if that will help me because from my understanding that's for accessing the server from outside my home network. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Since I'm new to this, I'm not sure what additional information might be relevant and help solve the problem. I'm happy to grab screenshots or additional details from my setup if needed.

Comment: That is quite a tall order. It can't be answered in one post here, probably more a hefty set of books. Please look at how to ask questions here, your question is essentially unanswerable. Look around for tutorials on the backend technologies that interest you (there are several alternatives and combinations). We want concrete questions that can get precise, complete answers in a page or so,

Answer (score 1):

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

By default Angular doesn't allow access from outside of localhost.
'0.0.0.0' would allow that